# I'm trying to achieve floating parallax image widget to implement on elementor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, elementor

I'm trying to achieve floating parallax image widget to implement on Elementor but I don't have Elementor pro , Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I have tried few code snippets as an example please see below

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var parallaxImage = document.querySelector(".parallax-image");
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    var scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
    parallaxImage.classList.toggle("active", scrollPosition > 0);
  });
});
```

```css
.parallax-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
}
/*
.parallax-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="parallax-container">
  <div class="parallax-image"> <img src="YOUR_IMAGE_URL" alt="Parallax Image"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no code!

Comment: `<div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax-image">
        <img src="YOUR_IMAGE_URL" alt="Parallax Image">
    </div>
</div>
.parallax-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 400px; /* Adjust the height as needed */
}

.parallax-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8; /* Adjust opacity as needed */
}

Comment: <script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var parallaxImage = document.querySelector(".parallax-image");

    window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        var scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
        parallaxImage.classList.toggle("active", scrollPosition > 0);
    });
});
</script>

Comment: I'm sorry Stack overflow didn't let me put the code

Comment: yes it does, you just did it wrong ... use `{}` button

Comment: I don't understand you want the whole code again? with flower brackets

Comment: no, don't worry about it if you can't figure out the buttons in the editor here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please click [edit] to create a [mcve]. In the question editor there's the `<>` icon that's used to create snippets. Read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/383904 Welcome to Stack Overflow.